# How do I use Entity framework to call a stored procedure when it exists in a schema different to dbo?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

My DBA has moved all my SQL Server stored procedures from the dbo schema to a different schema. As a result of this, my EF code can no longer find my stored procedures. I'm aware of the table attribute in which I can specify a different schema. However, I need to specify the schema in which the stored procedure exists.

Answer (score 0):

just concatenate your schema with a dot before your proc :

```
sqlString = "Exec " + ConnectiontoSql.GetSchemaName() + ".spName .......
```

Comment: That means manually editing the context.cs file and the change will be lost when the model is rebuilt.Also, it doesn't work because "The container '<schema name>' specified for the FunctionImport could not be found in the current workspace."